# Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, jekyll

I downloaded the new material bootstrap css and wanted to use it in my jekyll blog. After setting up and running the `jekyll serve -w` to compile the site locally, the console returned this error

`Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'css/main.scss': Invalid CSS after "...x-highlighting"": expected selector or at-rule, was ""bootstrap"" on line 49`

After searching for a while, it seems as if I am the only one facing this issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This can be interesting to see you code. If not all from a github repository, at least the `css/main.scss`.

Comment: There is, actually `bootstrap-sass` that you can customize and recompile on-the-fly with Jekyll's Sass converter. It's of no relevance to this problem, but give it a try.

Comment: I wanted to use the paper (material design) theme from bootswatch.com/paper/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by an omitted comma after one of my import statements

```
@import
    "base",
    "layout",
    "syntax-highlighting",
    "bootstrap";
```

Hope this saves someone else some time.

Comment: 9 years later, this is still relevant, heh (just spent 20 minutes trying to find that missing semicolon...)

Answer (score 6):

In github Pages, set main folder to /(root), not docs. Hope it works

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Big thanks for this, was confused as to what my mistake was!

Comment: Thanks!
It has worked on my Angular project

Answer (score 2):

You can also check if you're starting the server in the right directory, in my case, I spend 1 hour trying to start the server in the wrong directory :(

Comment: Had the same issue, turns out I mapped the start in a 'docs' folder which didn't exist. Dropping my index.html and .css file in a 'docs' folder solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

setting main folder to /(root) worked for my own problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually thrown when there is a typo or malformed CSS string in one of the `*.sass` files.

The error returned during the build is pointing to the issue. Just have in mind that the given line in the error is the one in bundled output css file:  `_site/css/main.css`.

Using `--trace` might help further investigate in some cases. i.e.:
`bundle exec jekyll build --trace`

Answer (score 0):

You can trace same problem in your local pc as below

```
bundle exec jekyll build --trace
```

then fix problem and push